# Is there a functor in namespace std that assigns to a variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for something like

```
string str;
some_function_that_calls_callback(std::[name]<string>(str))
```

Where [name] is a functor that assigns the value passed into it to the given variable.  Is that already in the standard library?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to assign to what. You've just given `str` as the sole function argument and `string` to what appears to be a template argument.

Comment: You could emulate it with lambda.

Comment: `[&str](auto val){ str = val; }`

Comment: @EdgarRokjān You can emulate all of the standard functors with a lambda, but it's often more readable to just write the name of a well known functor.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux something equivalent to [&str] (string arg) { str = arg; }

Comment: Can you provide some pseudocode to demonstrate exactly what you mean? And maybe an example of what this would be useful for?

Comment: @Galik I assume they want a way to easily create functors like the mentioned `[&str] (string arg) { str = arg; }`, using some syntax similar to `foo(str)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's right, if I had to give it a name maybe std::assign<string>(str)?